# Is there a minimum expiration date to travel to Canada with Australian Passport

Tags: passports, canada, australian-citizens

If my passport expires 2months after we travel and return from Cananda is that okay? Or do we need a new passport that has at least 6 months validity after we return?

Answer (score 5):

Canada, in general, does not have a requirement that passports be valid beyond the return date that the traveler has booked, so you should have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Australia to Canada doesn't have such restriction 6 months validity.

You can travel with passport expiring in 2 months.